# Converting alphanumeric to a date type and using DATEDIFF

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2012, datediff

I have the following query:

```
Select MFG.MFGNUM_0, AUH.ID1_0 , AUL.SEQ_0 , AUL.OVAL_0,
  AUL.NVAL_0 , AUL.COL_0, AUH.EVT_0 , 
  MFG.MFGTRKFLG_0, MFG.MFGSTA_0 , AUH.ADOUSR_0,
  AUH.HOU_0  , CAST(REPLACE(AUL.OVAL_0,'/','') as INT) , 
  (CAST(REPLACE(AUL.NVAL_0,'/','') as INT)) 

from x3v6.CICPRODAVC.AUDITH AUH  

  left outer join x3v6.CICPRODAVC.MFGHEAD MFG on MFG.MFGNUM_0 = AUH.ID1_0

  left outer join x3v6.CICPRODAVC.AUDITL AUL on AUH.SEQ_0 = AUL.SEQ_0

  where STA_0 = 2 and TBL_0 = 'MFGHEAD' and 
    ( AUL.COL_0 = 'ENDDAT' ) and MFG.MFGTRKFLG_0 < 4
```

Which returns:

```
MFGNUM_0    ID1_0   SEQ_0   OVAL_0     NVAL_0    COL_0  EVT_0   MFGTRKFLG_0  MFGSTA_0   ADOUSR_0    HOU_0   (No column name)    (No column name)
WO001170    WO001170 45088 29/01/2017 28/01/2017 ENDDAT UPDATE      1           1       MIR          093734        29012017        28012017
```

I want to do a subtraction between the 2 dates (NVAL) and OVAL , but the fields are alphanumeric and I am unable to successfuly use `CAST/CONVERT` and `DATEDIFF` to find the correct solution. I tried to use `REPLACE` and do a subtraction, but that didn't work either.

The version of SQL-SRV is 2012R.

Comment: Do you have an example of what NVAL and OVAL look like? Are they always formatted as: MM/DD/YYYY ?

Comment: DD/MM/YYYY is the format

Answer (score 0):

You can try this(*Tested on SQL Server*):

```
DECLARE @DATE1 VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE @DATE2 VARCHAR(10);

SET @DATE1 = '29/01/2017';
SET @DATE2 = '25/01/2017';

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(datetime, @DATE2 , 103),CONVERT(datetime, @DATE1 , 103)) AS DIFF;
```

> Since the OP doesn't know how to adapt his original query, is just as simple as:

```
SELECTt MFG.MFGNUM_0, AUH.ID1_0 , AUL.SEQ_0 , 
 AUL.OVAL_0, AUL.NVAL_0 , 
 DATEDIFF(DAY,CONVERT(datetime, AUL.NVAL_0 , 103),CONVERT(datetime, AUL.OVAL_0, 103)) DIFF, 
 AUL.COL_0, AUH.EVT_0 , 
 MFG.MFGTRKFLG_0, MFG.MFGSTA_0 , AUH.ADOUSR_0,
 AUH.HOU_0  , CAST(REPLACE(AUL.OVAL_0,'/','') as INT) , 
 (CAST(REPLACE(AUL.NVAL_0,'/','') as INT)) 
FROM x3v6.CICPRODAVC.AUDITH AUH  
 LEFT OUTER JOIN x3v6.CICPRODAVC.MFGHEAD MFG ON(MFG.MFGNUM_0 = AUH.ID1_0)
 left outer join x3v6.CICPRODAVC.AUDITL AUL ON(AUH.SEQ_0 = AUL.SEQ_0)
WHERE STA_0 = 2 and TBL_0 = 'MFGHEAD' AND
( AUL.COL_0 = 'ENDDAT' ) and MFG.MFGTRKFLG_0 < 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the concept, but how would this work without inputting literal values like exact dates?

Comment: Just replace `@DATE2` with `NVAL_0` and `@DATE1` with `OVAL_0` in your query :)

Answer (score 0):

What Hackerman put together is cleaner but here's another way:

```
DECLARE @nval varchar(100) = '30/11/2010';
DECLARE @oval varchar(100) = '16/07/2010';

SELECT ABS(DATEDIFF(DAY, nval, oval)) -- Note: change DAY to whatever date type you want to compare...
FROM (VALUES(
   CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@nval,7,4), SUBSTRING(@nval,4,2), SUBSTRING(@nval,1,2)) AS date),
   CAST(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@oval,7,4), SUBSTRING(@oval,4,2), SUBSTRING(@oval,1,2)) AS date)
)) dates(nval, oval);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand the concept, but how would this work without inputting literal values like exact dates?

Comment: Yes, my example was more about showing you a technique. You can replace my variables with real columns in a table.